# Problem with iptables forwarding

Tags: iptables, firewall, port

I have one linux with 2 interfaces example eth0 and eth1 one "external" and other "internal"
I want to redirect one port from external interface to internal interface and I have some problem to the RETURN of the package. However if I made this forward from external to external didn´t have problem. 
The iptables code that works on external to external and do this is:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport (port number) -j DNAT --to-destination (ipdestiny internal):(port destiny who are listening in the host in this case is the same of dport)
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d (ipdestiny internal) --dport (port number) -j SNAT --to-source (ip external)
```

If I have do a tcpdump:
TCPdump in the "internal eth":

```
09:53:55.099904 IP (tos 0x8, ttl 127, id 21212, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ipexternal.(61236 port origin) > ipinternal.(port destiny): Flags [S], cksum 0x1aba (correct), seq 3030159247, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
        0x0000:  4508 0034 52dc 4000 7f06 832b 0ac8 2840  E..4R.@....+..(@
        0x0010:  c0a8 3204 ef34 0050 b49c 8f8f 0000 0000  ..2..4.P........
        0x0020:  8002 faf0 1aba 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0308  ................
        0x0030:  0101 0402
```

As I can see the traffic to the internal forward works but nothing "come back" from the internal to the external. 
I had checked the /etc/sysctl.conf the line with:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

And it´s uncommented.

here its how I see the nat table:

```
iptables -t nat -L -n

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:(port number listening on "external") to:(destiny ip "internal"):(port destiny in the "internal")

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            (ip destiny)       tcp dpt:(port number listening on "external") to:(ip "external")


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

The client is probably receiving the traffic, but does not know where to send return traffic to. On the client machine, define a static route or default gateway.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: It does suggest a course of action (define a static route or default gateway)...